# Resampling PCM audio windows store app

Tags: windows-runtime, audio-recording, wasapi

With the help of following [example code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/525620/Recording-audio-to-WAV-with-WASAPI-in-Windows-Stor), I successfully wrote an application to capture microphone audio in PCM format.
The following is the wave format of the captured PCM audio:

```
Channels = 2
FormatTag = Pcm
SamplesPerSecond = 44100
BitsPerSample = 32
BlockAlign = 8           
AverageBytesPerSecond = 352800
```

I want to resample the PCM audio to the following wave type:

```
Channels = 1
FormatTag = Pcm
SamplesPerSecond = 8000
BitsPerSample = 16
BlockAlign = 2              
AverageBytesPerSecond = 16000
```

Forums are saying that we can capture audio in CD quality only from windows store apps, is this true? Is it possible to convert the wave type of PCM audio in windows store app?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of this has anything to do with "CD quality". And I don't think Windows Store is relevant to your question.

WASAPI uses the format of the sound card, whatever it is. Usually it's stereo, 16 bit, 44.1 or 48 kHz, but it could be anything.

You will have to write the [resampler](http://atrilla.net/data/files/mratedsp.pdf) and design the [low-pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_pass_filter#Simple_infinite_impulse_response_filter) yourself.

Are you sure WASAPI is the best match for your use case? Have you considered a higher level API ([DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [XAudio2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh405049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) that handles resampling for you instead?